# Laravel detectEnvironment - how to combine machine name and server variable?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, environment-variables

In Laravel 4.2, I'm using App::detectEnvironment to change database according to machine name. I also now need to have it change environment according to an environment variable. I've tried to combine but it doesn't work at the moment and I'm not sure how to combine the two techniques.

Using machine name:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

            'local' => array('.local', 'homestead'), 
            'staging' => array('ip-staging'), 
            'production' => array('ip-production')
    ) 
);
```

Using a server environment variable:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
{
    // Default to local if LARAVEL_ENV is not set
    return getenv('LARAVEL_ENV') ?: 'local'; 
}
```

Non-working combined code looks like:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
{
    // Default to machine name if LARAVEL_ENV is not set
    return getenv('LARAVEL_ENV') ?: array(

        'local' => array('.local', 'homestead'), 
        'staging' => array('ip-staging'), 
        'production' => array('ip-production')
    ); 

});
```

Comment: have you tried with your super global variable too? `return isset($_ENV['LARAVEL_ENV']) ? $_ENV['LARAVEL_ENV'] : array(...);` - can be substituted with $_SERVER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer - thanks to @Marwelln's hint.

The `$env` variable needs to come from the `detectEnvironment` function for it to be recognised by Laravel.

```
if (getenv('LARAVEL_ENV')) 
{
    $env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
    {
            return getenv('LARAVEL_ENV');
    });
} 
else 
{
    $env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
            // local development environments are set with machine host names
            // developers find this out by typing 'hostname' at command line

            'local' => array('*.local', 'homestead'), 
            'staging' => array('ip-staging'), 
            'production' => array('ip-production')
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. It sets to environment to what you have in `getenv('LARAVEL_ENV')` if it's set, otherwise it uses the default `$app->detectEnvironment` method.

```
$env = getenv('LARAVEL_ENV') ?: $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'local' => array('.local', 'homestead'), 
    'staging' => array('ip-staging'), 
    'production' => array('ip-production')
));
```